# Как сложить элементы списков разной длины в Python

Tags: python

Итак.

Есть задача: сложить цифры во времени для получения 34 и вывести комбинаций этих цифр.

Пример: 19:59:57 будет 1+9+5+9+5+5 = 34, значит нужно вывести эту комбинацию 195957

В итоге нужно вывести все комбинации цифр, которые дают 34 (но при этом чтобы они были именно в формате времени, то есть первая цифра не может быть больше 2 и т.д.)

Пока выходит так (пока только начало):

```
# Часы, минуты, секунды и 10 для деления
a = list(range(24))
b = list(range(60))
c = list(range(60))
d = 10

# Нужно сложить целочисленное деление и остаток
a1 = [x // d for x in a]
a2 = [x % d for x in a]
a3 =  

b1 = [x // d for x in b]
b2 = [x % d for x in b]
b3 =  

c1 = [x // d for x in c]
c2 = [x % d for x in c]
c3 =  

d1 = 

print (d1)
```

Не знаю как сложить теперь каждый элемент трех списков друг с другом (если складывать при помощи zip, то получается что они складываются попарно и оставшиеся элементы в списках не складываются)

Comment: @insolor, ok, спасибо за информацию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for h in range(24):
    for m in range(60):
        for s in range(60):
            if h // 10 + h % 10 + m // 10 + m % 10 + s // 10 + s % 10 == 34:
                print(f'{h:02}{m:02}{s:02}')
```

https://ideone.com/RHFSSO

Comment: двоеточия пропущены между часами:минутами:секундами

Comment: @Интик, по условию задачи двоеточия не нужны, нужно просто перечислить все цифры

Answer (score 0):

```
import time


class Clock:
    def __init__(self, h=0, m=0, s=0):
        self.h = h
        self.m = m
        self.s = s - 1

    def __next__(self):
        self.s += 1
        if self.s == 60:
            self.s = 0
            self.m += 1
        if self.m == 60:
            self.h += 1
            self.m = 0
        if self.h == 24:
            self.s = 0
            self.m = 0
            self.h = 0
        return f"{self.h:02}:{self.m:02}:{self.s:02} - {self.h + self.m + self.s}"

    def __iter__(self):
        self.h = 0
        self.m = 0
        self.s = 0
        return self


clock = Clock()

for i in clock:
    print(i)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Как это относится к вопросу?

Comment: Ну готовый код же. Только другой вариант решения. Чутка подправить, лишнее там удалить.

Comment: Именно: почти все удалить, и почти все исправить. Т.е. просто все.